# remove the column header menu in the locked columns from the Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I want to remove the column header menu in one of the locked columns in my kendo grid. i have tried the bellow but it only works for the columns that are not locked.

```js
function removeColumnheaderMenu(gridId) {

 var grid = $(gridId).data("kendoGrid");
 grid.thead.find("[data-field=lockedColumnIwantToRemove]>.k-header-column-menu").remove();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a possible solution for you.

http://dojo.telerik.com/exAje

```
var menuItems =  $("div.k-grid-header-locked").find("a.k-header-column-menu");

          console.log(menuItems);

          if(menuItems !== null && menuItems.length > 0) 
          {
            menuItems.each(function(){
              $(this).remove();
            });
          }

        });
```

all this does is inspect the locked side of the grid and then checks to see if there is a column menu link and then removes any it finds.

If you need any more details on what this is doing or need it modifying to be a bit more robust give me a shout.